# GenericViews - and pushing model name in URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

using Django Generic CreateView - is it possible for me to pass a value into the CreateView from the URL call, that defines which model/table to base the view on?

I did try get_context_data  but believe that is not the solution, as I think it only pushes it to the rendered template.

You will see from my scripts - I am pushing the value 'syslog_policy' - i would like the view to set the model variable to be, what-ever value I push from the URL.

The reason for this, I have some pages/models that are similar - so rather than create multiple html pages and views - I wouldn't need to if I could get this to work.

### URL Call

`<li><a href="{% url 'security_app:HardenTemplateCreate' 'syslog_policy' %}">Update/Delete Policies</a></li>`

### urls.py

`path('HardenTemplateCreate/<str:element>', HardenTemplateCreate.as_view(success_url="/security_tooling/add_success") ,name="HardenTemplateCreate")`

### views.py

````
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['element']= self.kwargs['element']
        print(context['element'])
        return context

    model = !!<NEED VALUE SUPPLIED IN URL HERE>!!
    fields = ['name','template']
    template_name = 'security_app/add.html'```
````

Comment: You can pass an argument to the url like this: ```<li><a href="{% url 'security_app:HardenTemplateCreate' element='syslog_policy' %}">Update/Delete Policies</a></li>```. But what is the goal exactly? You need a modelform to be constructed based on the model that is indicated in the url?

Comment: correct - model to be based on what is specified in the URL @twrought

Comment: I feel like this is probably easier with modelforms and separate views perhaps, but I shared a possible way to do it like this!

Answer (score 0):

This would assume that all the models we are working with here belong to the same app (`main`) - if not, you also need to pass that to form kwargs and handle accordingly. In forms.py:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.forms.models import fields_for_model

class VariableModelForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model_name = kwargs.pop('model_name', None)
        model = apps.get_model(app_label='main', model_name=model_name)
        model_fields = fields_for_model(model)
        super(VariableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in model_fields:
            self.fields[field] = model_fields[field]
```

In your CreateView:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form']= VariableModelForm(model_name=self.kwargs['modelname'])
        return context
```

You grab the model name from the url kwargs, pass it to your form as an extra positional argument, and use it in your form's **init** method to set up the fields.